# Can you change the voice for twilio?

Tags: api, twilio

I'm using the  verb on Twilio, and when the command is activated it says what ever text you put within the tag. Currently it's set to a male computer voice. I'm wondering if there are any options / ways to change the voice? I would prefer a female voice as they tend to sound better on the phone. 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<Say voice="woman">Hello Phil</Say>
```

Documentation can be found here: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/2010-04-01/twiml/say

Answer (score 0):

There is a new option: `<Say voice="alice">Hello Phil</Say>`.  Alice allows setting of the language as well.  It is not clear if Alice has improved pronunciation.